# How can I properly insert structures into an ArrayList?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, structure

I have a programming assignment in VB to get me used to ArrayLists and Structures. I understand that the best way to do this atm is to use a List, but the prof wants me using arraylists with a structure. I have a form application that requires the user to input customer details (name, account #, balance) which is saved to an arraylist as a structure. The program requires that if a user makes a change to an account, and then presses the "Next" or "Previous" buttons to page away, the arraylist will be updated with the changes that were made. This is where I got so far in my program. When I click Next or Previous the program crashes, and I get the following error on the the balance account Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. I dont understand why it wont accept a double or an integer from the textbox, when in the Save and Add subs it works fine.

```
Public Class AccountInformationForm

    Dim objaccount As account
    Dim accounts As New ArrayList
    Dim count As Integer

    Public Structure account

        Public RecordNum As Integer
        Public FirstName As String
        Public LastName As String
        Public balance As Double
        Public account As Integer
    End Structure

    Private Sub AccountInformationForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        count = 0
        objaccount.RecordNum = 0
        objaccount.FirstName = "Jesus"
        objaccount.LastName = "Christ"
        objaccount.balance = 100
        objaccount.account = 1

        accounts.Add(objaccount)


        'Display First Record
        firstTextBox.Text = objaccount.FirstName
        lastTextBox.Text = objaccount.LastName
        balanceTextBox.Text = objaccount.balance
        accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.account



    End Sub


    Private Sub nextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nextButton.Click

        objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
        objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
        objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
        objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text

        accounts.Insert(count, objaccount)


        count += 1

        If count > (accounts.Count - 1) Then
            count = 0

        End If

        'Display Current Record
        firstTextBox.Text = accounts(count).FirstName
        lastTextBox.Text = accounts(count).LastName
        balanceTextBox.Text = accounts(count).balance
        accountTextBox.Text = accounts(count).account

    End Sub


    Private Sub previousButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles previousButton.Click
        'Before paging away, save the current form data in the current record
        objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
        objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
        objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
        objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text

        accounts.Insert(count, objaccount)

        count -= 1

        If count < 0 Then
            count = accounts.Count - 1
        End If



        firstTextBox.Text = accounts(count).FirstName
        lastTextBox.Text = accounts(count).LastName
        balanceTextBox.Text = accounts(count).balance
        accountTextBox.Text = accounts(count).account

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim upper As Integer = accounts.Count
        objaccount.RecordNum = (upper + 1)



        If firstTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
        End If

        If lastTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
        End If

        If balanceTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
        End If

        If accountTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text
        End If

        accounts.Add(objaccount)


        firstTextBox.Clear()
        lastTextBox.Clear()
        balanceTextBox.Clear()
        accountTextBox.Clear()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click


        If firstTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.FirstName = firstTextBox.Text
        End If

        If lastTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.LastName = lastTextBox.Text
        End If

        If balanceTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
        End If

        If accountTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a name")
        Else
            objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text
        End If

        accounts.Add(objaccount)


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        firstTextBox.Clear()
        lastTextBox.Clear()
        balanceTextBox.Clear()
        accountTextBox.Clear()


        Dim upper As Integer = accounts.Count
        objaccount.RecordNum = (upper + 1)
        accountTextBox.Text = objaccount.RecordNum

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        accounts.RemoveAt(count)

        count = count - 1
        firstTextBox.Text = accounts(count).FirstName
        lastTextBox.Text = accounts(count).LastName
        balanceTextBox.Text = accounts(count).balance
        accountTextBox.Text = accounts(count).account

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just dumping your code and expecting us to trawl through it in the hope of finding something wrong is not acceptable here I'm afraid.  SO is for SPECIFIC questions.  It's up to you to isolate exactly what is not working as you expect and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of that, which would include just the RELEVANT code.  You need to either tell us what error message you're getting and where or else explain what behaviour you're seeing and how it differs from your expectation.  If you can't do that then posting here is premature.

Comment: I thought my question was detailed enough to point out that the problem is in the button click subs for next and previous, as soon as I click next, or previous the program crashes and I get "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid" on the balance account.

Comment: It was not.  You said that that was a requirement but you didn't say that that wasn't working and you certainly didn't say that you were getting a specific error message.  This is not stuff that we should have to guess.  Please edit your question and remove all irrelevant code and add all missing relevant information.  Others who want to help shouldn't have to go through the comments to find what they need.

Comment: As for the issue, the error message is telling you all you need to know.  You're trying to convert a `String` to a `Double` but the `String` is empty.  Now it's up to you to debug and determine why that's happening.  VS is an IDE, not a text editor, so don't just use it as a text editor.  Debug your code.  Use breakpoints.  Step through it and examine your data as the code executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is exactly as the exception describes, you're not converting strings to/from numbers correctly. The reason the Add/Save subs work is that you are checking for the .Text <> "" first, so rather than ending up trying to convert a string into a number format, the user gets prompted to enter data therefore a conversion is never attempted, so an exception won't be thrown.

If you change all the occurences of the following:

```
balanceTextBox.Text = accounts(count).balance
accountTextBox.Text = accounts(count).account
```

to:

```
balanceTextBox.Text = accounts(count).balance.ToString
accountTextBox.Text = accounts(count).account.ToString
```

and also, conversely, change all occurrences of the following:

```
objaccount.balance = balanceTextBox.Text
objaccount.account = accountTextBox.Text
```

to something like:

```
Try
    objaccount.balance = Convert.ToDouble(balanceTextBox.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    objaccount.balance = 0
End Try
Try
    objaccount.account = Convert.ToInt32(accountTextBox.Text)
Catch ex As Exception
    objaccount.account = 0
End Try
```

then you will no longer get that unhandled exception. In the catch block, you could either show a messagebox like you've been doing or just set the values to 0 as shown above. In the future, I would recommend you add **Option Strict On** as the first line of your code. Without it, implicit conversions are done for you, but that also opens up the door for exceptions like the one you encountered when the String = Nothing. If you turn that option on, any conversions you are doing incorrectly will be highlighted/underlined in visual studio. It's best practice to do those types of things explicitly and strongly type your code anyway; there are less surprises that way so it's a good habit to get into.